# Plotting adiabatics

Tags: plotting

I have the following code for drawing two isotherms for a Carnot engine:

```
R = 8.3*(10^3); n = 1; 
P[V_, T_] := n*R*T/V 
Plot[{P[V, T = 355], P[V, T = 295], P[V = 0.0006, T = 295]}, {V, 0.0008, 0.0036}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Volume (cubic meters)", "Pressure (N/m^2)"}]
```

It's fine (though a word on how to exaggerate the vertical proportions *without* the aspect ratio command would be great).

But, what I want to do is plot the sides of this Carnot cycle problem -- I can get the isotherms, but when I add a third expression (like one where a different variable is held constant, i.e. volume) it seems to choke on it. Anyhow, any help for someone who knows almost nothing about *Mathematica* :-) `Overlay` didn't seem to do it.

Comment: I was *sorely* tempted to insert [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Gadus_morhua_Cod-2b-Atlanterhavsparken-Norway.JPG/800px-Gadus_morhua_Cod-2b-Atlanterhavsparken-Norway.JPG) after the phrase "I have the following cod", but I restrained myself and fixed the typo instead.

Comment: @RahulNarain such puns give me a haddock.

Comment: ho ho. Anyhow, I think I figure out the issue, but I am still thinking about vertical scaling. Aspectratio doesn't seem to really do it, and there doesn't seem to be a way to control how Mathematica scales things to "zoom in" on an axis in a specific way.

Comment: @rcollyer, RahulNarain [this](http://www.fishpuns.com/) is definitely of interest. Jesse how else would you be able to exaggerate the vertical proportions? And what is it that you dislike about aspect ratio?

Comment: It's just that when I plot the two isotherms the lines look a bit close together, and I'd like to skew the scaling of the vertical axis so they appear farther apart. Like if you had a graph of some function where the x-axis is long and the variations in they-axis small, you want to exaggerate the vertical scaling.

Comment: @gpap those are brill-ant. Ouch.

Comment: You mention that your problem involves a third expression, but don't give the expression. Since it's an adiabate, you're talking about `T^2/V^(5/3)` - but it's unclear what you're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use the [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Epilog.html) option to plot the lines of constant volume. Like so:

```
R = 8.3*(10^3); n = 1;
P[V_, T_] := n*R*T/V
Plot[{P[V, 355], P[V, 295]}, {V, 0.0008, 0.0036},
  PlotStyle -> Black,
  ImageSize -> {450, 450},
  AspectRatio -> 1.2,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Volume (cubic meters)", "Pressure (N/m^2)"}, 
  Epilog -> 
    {Line[{{0.0008, P[0.0008, 355]}, {0.0008, P[0.0008, 295]}}], 
     Line[{{0.0036, P[0.0036, 355]}, {0.0036, P[0.0036, 295]}}]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: should be 'lines of constant volume'

Comment: @ubpdqn. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1):

I post this for variety.
`ContourPlot` can also be used:

The following has arguments of two volumes and two temperatures.

```
ada[v1_, v2_, t1_, t2_] := Module[{r = 8.31 10^3, ep, lns},
  lns = {AbsoluteThickness[2], Line[#]} & /@ 
    Partition[
     ep = {#[[1]], #[[2]] r/#[[1]]} & /@ Tuples[{{v1, v2}, {t1, t2}}],
      2];
  ContourPlot[{p v/r == t1, p v/r == t2}, {v, v1, v2}, {p, 
    Min[ep[[All, 2]]], Max[ep[[All, 2]]]}, 
   ContourStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[2], 
      Red}, {AbsoluteThickness[2], Blue}}, 
   PlotLegends -> {StringForm["T=``  K", t1], 
     StringForm["T= `` K", t2]}, Epilog -> lns, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Volume (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(m\), \(3\)]\))", 
     "Pressure (Pa)"}, BaseStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Kartika"}]
  ]
```

Illustrating:

```
ada[0.0006, 0.0038, 295, 355]
```

[image]

Or using `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ada[0.0006, v, 295, t], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.0040}, {0, 5 10^9}}], {v, 0.0010, 0.0038}, {t, 
  300, 355}]
```

[image]